# How can I add service annotation in istio operator patch

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, istio

I am installing istio 1.6.0 using `istioctl` with below config file:

```
--
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  profile: default
  components:
    egressGateways:
      - name: istio-egressgateway
        enabled: true
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          overlays:
          - kind: Service
            name: istio-ingressgateway
            patches:
            - path: spec.loadBalancerIP
              value: x.x.x.x
            - path: spec.externalTrafficPolicy
              value: Local
            - path: metadata.annotations.[service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group]
              value: az-rg-group
```

This part giving me an error:

```
- path: metadata.annotations.[service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group]
  value: az-rg-group
```

> Error: failed to apply manifests: errors occurred during operation

Path is not correct for annotation. How can I provide a path of annotation with valid syntax?

Following this sample code: https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/operator/samples/pilot-advanced-override.yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new field for service annotations. The issue was raised here https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/20078

Please refer the following example
[ingressgateway_k8s_settings.yaml](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/ca541df418d0902ebeb9506c84d24c6bd9743801/operator/cmd/mesh/testdata/manifest-generate/input/ingressgateway_k8s_settings.yaml#L14-L15)

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  components:
    pilot:
      enabled: false
    ingressGateways:
    - namespace: istio-system
      name: istio-ingressgateway
      enabled: true
      k8s:
        service:
          externalTrafficPolicy: Local
        serviceAnnotations:
          manifest-generate: "testserviceAnnotation"
        securityContext:
          sysctls:
          - name: "net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range"
            value: "80 65535"
```

Comment: For anyone like me noticing the link above is broken, [this link is bound to a commit instead of an ever changing reference](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/ca541df418d0902ebeb9506c84d24c6bd9743801/operator/cmd/mesh/testdata/manifest-generate/input/ingressgateway_k8s_settings.yaml#L14-L15).

Comment: Thanks, Updated the link in the answer with the file.

Comment: Why set `pilot: enabled: false`?

Comment: it is just a component for sidecars and is set to disable, you can enable it, along with other fields. The original question was about how to enable service annotations.
More info here:
https://istio.io/v1.8/docs/reference/commands/pilot-agent/